# Почему первый вариант кода лучше второго?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Мне сказали что первый вариант кода правильней чем второй.

```js
var average = function(num1, num2) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + arguments[i];
  }
  return sum / arguments.length;
};
console.log(average());
console.log(average(12));
console.log(average(1, 4, 5));
```

Второй вариант-это написал я. И я считаю что так лучше.

```js
var average = function() {
  var i;
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + arguments[i];
  }
  return sum / arguments.length;
};
console.log(average());
console.log(average(12));
console.log(average(1, 4, 5));
```

Мне сделали намек,что надо в первую очередь сделать функцию с аргументами (1 пример). Но ведь функция может принять неопределенное количество аргументов.
Подскажите,где я не прав и почему?

Comment: в такой формулировке первый код это ересь какая-то. определять параметры и не использовать их это не есть хорошо. намекните об этом тому кто писал первый код. Если оба варианта писали вы, то вероятно намек вы не поняли, и он был о другом.

Comment: я конечно не супер про, но второй вариант мне нравится больше. Поясню: 1) определение переменной i вынесено за цикл, хоть это и микрооптимизация. 2) есть условие, что число аргументов может быть любым. По мне ты прав.

Comment: Мой написан второй вариант. А первый варинант-это отредактированный,но не мной.

Comment: Пахнет бредом. Мне кажется вы даете не всю задачу. Зачем в функции  задавать аргументы и не использовать их?

Comment: Это не задача. Я практикуюсь просто. Это единственная функция.

Comment: А почему не передать в функцию один массив и не заниматься "магией"?

Comment: Я еще не сильно понимаю о чем Вы. Просто я не могу понять,что не правильно в моем варианте, и почему он плохой.

Comment: Думаю что ход мыслей был такой. Что бы получить среднее значение надо минимум 2 числа. Добавив их таким образом критик, "гарантировал" наличае как минимум 2-х параметров, но при этом полностью пропустил валидацию.

Comment: Я имел в виду что будет типа того: `var average = function(values) {`, `for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {`, `console.log(average([1, 2, 3]));`